# Вывод преобразованного массива символов из строки (Java)

Tags: java

Дорогие товарищи, добрый день! Прошу прощения за вопрос, но в голове не укладывается. Суть такова, имеем строку, преобразовываем её в массив с помощью метода toCharArray и выводим массив на экран. Как мы знаем, массив просто так вывести не получится и надо пробегать по его ячейкам с помощью циклов. Что я и сделал, но потом решил попробовать вывести преобразование сразу на экран, по моей логике это не должно было сработать, так как метод преобразования строки в массив символов toCharArray() возвращает массив символов, а его просто так не вывести на экран. Наведите пожалуйста на правильную мысль, если можно более простым языком, я только изучаю программирование, простые для вас вещи сложны для меня. Спасибо. Прилагаю код.

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "ABCDF";
    System.out.println(str.toCharArray());
    //char[] charFromString = str.toCharArray(); // {A, B, C, D, F}
    // check our array
    //for (char i : charFromString) {
    //    System.out.print(i + " ");
    //}
}
```

}

Comment: `но потом решил попробовать вывести преобразование сразу на экран` что это значит?

Comment: Добрый день, это значит  System.out.println(str.toCharArray());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Преобразование массивов в строку

Когда в Java говорят о том, что «массив просто так не вывести на экран», то имеют ввиду то, что метод `toString` для массивов возвращает не текстовое представление содержимого массива (что ожидается), а некую строку содержащую тип и адрес памяти:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
System.out.println(array); //[I@54bedef2
```

Метод `toString` работает аналогичным образом и для массивов `char`:

```
String str = "ABCDF";
System.out.println(str.toCharArray().toString()); //[C@2ff4acd0
```

Обычно если нужно вывести содержимое массива в строку используют методы [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(char%5B%5D)) или [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) (для многомерных массивов):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.toCharArray())); //[A, B, C, D, F]
```

### Вывод массива символов

Почему же `System.out.println(str.toCharArray())` выводит строку? Потому что поле `System.out` возвращает экземпляр класса `PrintStream`, а этот класс перегружает метод [`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char%5B%5D)) именно для массивов типа `char[]`.

Посмотрите [документацию этого метода](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char%5B%5D)):

> Prints an array of characters and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes [`print(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char%5B%5D)) and then `println()`.
> *Выводит массив символов и затем завершает строку. Метод ведет как если бы вызвали [`print(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char%5B%5D)) и затем `println()`*

А также документацию [`print(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char%5B%5D)):

> Prints an array of characters. The characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.
> *Выводит массив символов. Символы преображаются в байты согласно кодировке по-умолчанию платформы, затем эти байты записываются точно так же как в методе `write(int)`*

Получается что метод `println` позволяет сразу вывести массив символов как текст. Поэтому именно массив символов можно «просто так» вывести на экран. В отличие от метода [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(char%5B%5D)) массив выводится без разделителей, как обычная строка.

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам за такое подробное описание. Я теперь понимаю как мыслить в дальнейшем. Единственное, чтобы полноценно разбираться - нужно читать документацию, чтобы читать документацию - нужно разбираться в программировании. Получается замкнутый круг. Но я буду стараться, возможно необходимо слепо действовать, воспринимая некоторые вещи как догму, а при приобретении опыта уже можно будет примерно понимать что написано в документации. Сейчас перепишу Ваш ответ к себе в конспект! Низкий поклон!

Comment: @Антон Пожалуйста! Да, что-то станет ясно сейчас, что-то после прочтения книги, некоторые вещи обретут смысл только после получения практического опыта. Не забудьте отметить ответ как решение (галочка слева).

Comment: Вы очень добры. За галочку тоже большое спасибо. Очередной новый опыт. Хорошего дня!